# Add JSON element in bash script

Tags: json, bash, shell, http

within my bash script I have a line that looks like this:

```
JOB_RESULTS=$(curl --fail -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --write-out HTTP_CODE='%{http_code}' "${request_url}")
```

This line outputs the following:

```
{"name":"callCLF010Job","id":11693,"status":"STARTING","message":"The job has started.","exitCode":"exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription="}HTTP_CODE=200
```

The problem is, I want to add the `HTTP_CODE` into the JSON message.

Is there a way to make the return look like `{"name":"callCLF010Job","id":11693,"status":"STARTING","message":"The job has started.","exitCode":"exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=","HTTP_CODE":"200"}`

EDIT:

With confettis changes my code looks like this:

```
http_code="${JOB_RESULTS:${#JOB_RESULTS}-17}"
http_body="${JOB_RESULTS:0:${#JOB_RESULTS}-17}"
http_code_json=", ${http_code}}"
my_result="${http_body/%\}/$http_code_json}"
```

when I run `echo $my_result` my output looks like this:

```
{"name":"callCLF010Job","id":11702,"status":"STARTING","message":"The job has started.","exitCode":"exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescriptio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use sed to format the output the way you want:

```
echo $JOB_RESULTS | sed 's/}HTTP_CODE=\([0-9]\+\)$/,"HTTP_CODE":"\1"}/'
```

Or inside your command:

```
JOB_RESULTS=$(curl --fail -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --write-out HTTP_CODE='%{http_code}' "${request_url}" | sed 's/}HTTP_CODE=\([0-9]\+\)$/,"HTTP_CODE":"\1"}/')
```

Comment: I want to be able to use jq to grab the code, for example:


`http_status=$(echo "${JOB_RESULTS}" | jq -r '.HTTP_CODE')`

Comment: I see that this formats the output, but what I want is to actually insert `HTTP_CODE` into the `$JOB_RESULTS`, so that if I echo'd just `$JOB_RESULTS` HTTP_CODE would appear there

Comment: In this case you can use sed inside your command. I edited the answer to show you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Murilo Dutra, that was very simple and exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

This is using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get the job done. (Pure bash, besides `curl`.)

```sh
curlout=$(curl -s --fail -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --write-out '"HTTP_CODE":"%{http_code}"' "http://example.com")
http_code="${curlout:${#curlout}-17}"
http_body="${curlout:0:${#curlout}-17}"
http_code_json=", ${http_code}}"
my_result="${http_body/%\}/$http_code_json}"
```

Replace `http://example.com` with the URL or variable of your choice.

In order to prevent errors in case of a wrong URL or (no) output, you should put the last four lines within an `if-construct`. E.g. `if [[ $http_code != '"HTTP_CODE":"000"' ]]`.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? my_result is missing some quotations and brackets, I'm not sure how you want this formatted. I want to be able to use jq to parse HTTP_CODE from the response

Comment: @Josh I'm sorry, I've had two stupid typos in my answer. I've edited it, please try it again now. `echo $my_result | jq .HTTP_CODE` does now print `"200"` for me. If you need a numeric value let me know then I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you edited, http_code_json seems to have an extra bracket, and for some reason the -17 in http_body is red highlighted in my vim syntax

Comment: I'll keep trying for now, you seem very close to what I'm looking for Thank you

Comment: @Josh I've had an `=` in my original answer for the JSON when it has to be a `:`. I tried my answer with `http://a.4cdn.org/boards.json` instead of `http://example.com` and it works flawlessly.

Comment: my code looks like this:

`http_code="${JOB_RESULTS:${#JOB_RESULTS}-17}"
http_body="${JOB_RESULTS:0:${#JOB_RESULTS}-17}"
http_code_json=", ${http_code}}"
my_result="${http_body/%\}/$http_code_json}"` 

but the output is like this:

`{"name":"callCLF010Job","id":11702,"status":"STARTING","message":"The job has started.","exitCode":"exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescriptio`

Comment: @Josh If you still have issues, please let me know your `bash --version`. The minimum you need is `4.2`.

Comment: @Josh Please note that you need to change your `curl` command too. The `--write-out` has to be `'"HTTP_CODE":"%{http_code}"'` and you need to add the `-s` flag.

Comment: I'm on bash version 4.3 I edited my question to make things more clear for you what I'm doing

Comment: @Josh Counting the characters of your OP now, I'm almost certain you didn't change your `curl` command to mine. Please try with the changes to the `curl` command.

Comment: You're correct, I'll give that a go. It works with those changes. Thank you for your help and creative solution